# SQL divide two columns

Tags: oracle

Let the following cinema database where a user may critic a movie and assign a score from 0 to 10 to his critic :

```
MOVIE (idMovie)
  PK (idMovie)
CRITICS (idMovie, user, score)
  PK (idMovie, user)
  FK (idMovie) REF MOVIE
  NN score
```

How would go about showing all movie IDs that have their average critics score over 80%? Something like :

```
WITH CMINUSEIGHT AS (
  SELECT C.idFilm, COUNT(C.idFilm) AS cpCount FROM CRITIQUE C
    WHERE C.note > 8
    GROUP BY C.idFilm),
  AVERAGE AS (
  SELECT C.idFilm, (COUNT(C.idFilm) / CP.cpCount * 100) AS cmCount FROM CRITIQUE C, CPLUSHUIT CP
    WHERE C.note < 9
    GROUP BY C.idFilm)
SELECT C.idFilm FROM CRITIQUE C, AVERAGE A
  WHERE C.idFilm = A.idFilm
  HAVING AVERAGE > 80;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the AVG aggregate function to accomplish this:

```
SELECT 
  idMovie, 
  AVG(score) AS AvgScore
FROM Critiques
GROUP BY idMovie
HAVING AVG(score) > 8
```